# Access SQL Count function with zeros

Tags: vba, ms-access, count, zero, isnull

Yes, there is a lot out there already on using Count in SQL along with a left join to get the zero values. However, I am using Access and I cannot get my SQL command to return any zero values. The two most promising solutions I've tried were

```
SELECT RQ.ServiceDate, NZ(COUNT(RQ2.Run), 0) AS RunCountForHour
From RealQuery As RQ
Left Join RealQuery As RQ2 ON  (RQ.Run = RQ2.Run) AND (RQ.ServiceDate = RQ2.ServiceDate)
WHERE RQ.ProviderId < 12 AND RQ.RunBeginTime <= 7200 And RQ.RunEndTime >= 7200 AND RQ.RunBeginTime <> 0 AND (RQ.ServiceDate BETWEEN #1/1/2015# AND #4/30/2015#) AND RQ.ServiceDate NOT IN (#1/19/2015#)
GROUP BY RQ.ServiceDate;
```

and

```
SELECT RQ.ServiceDate, COUNT(IIF(ISNULL(RQ2.Run), 0, RQ2.Run)) AS RunCountForHour
From RealQuery As RQ
Right Join RealQuery As RQ2 ON  (RQ.Run = RQ2.Run) AND (RQ.ServiceDate = RQ2.ServiceDate)
WHERE RQ.ProviderId < 12 AND RQ.RunBeginTime <= 7200 And RQ.RunEndTime >= 7200 AND RQ.RunBeginTime <> 0 AND (RQ.ServiceDate BETWEEN #1/1/2015# AND #4/30/2015#) AND RQ.ServiceDate NOT IN (#1/19/2015#)
GROUP BY RQ.ServiceDate;
```

But neither of these options output any data that had zero as the run count. Basically, the important parts should come from the Count in the first SELECT line, or somewhere in the JOIN I might have something wrong. I included the rest of the query though (with the whole long, convoluted where clause) just in case someone could see a reason why it might be screwing up the counts. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who offered solutions, but in the end I went with using the SUM feature along with IIF (I'm working in Access) instead of COUNT. The final code with correct output goes as follows:

```
SELECT RQ.ServiceDate, SUM(IIF((RQ.RunBeginTime <= 7200 AND RQ.RunEndTime >= 7200
AND RQ.RunBeginTime <> 0), 1, 0)) AS RunCountForHour
FROM RealQuery AS RQ WHERE RQ.ProviderId < 12 AND 
(RQ.ServiceDate BETWEEN #1/1/2015# AND #4/30/2015#) AND RQ.ServiceDate NOT IN (#1/19/2015#)
GROUP BY RQ.ServiceDate;
```

This gives me all the unique dates in the table along with run counts, even when the count is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause is asking for `RQ.RunBeginTime` to be `<> 0`, which first needs a row with `RQ.RunBeginTime` to exist. Thus your WHERE clause is excluding any rows that you want to show as zero. Try moving some conditions to the `JOIN ON` clause. Without test data I can't be sure, but try:

```
SELECT RQ.ServiceDate, NZ(COUNT(RQ2.Run), 0) AS RunCountForHour
From RealQuery As RQ
Left Join RealQuery As RQ2 ON  (RQ.Run = RQ2.Run) AND (RQ.ServiceDate = RQ2.ServiceDate) AND RQ.ProviderId < 12 AND RQ.RunBeginTime <= 7200 And RQ.RunEndTime >= 7200 AND RQ.RunBeginTime <> 0 AND (RQ.ServiceDate BETWEEN #1/1/2015# AND #4/30/2015#) AND RQ.ServiceDate NOT IN (#1/19/2015#)
GROUP BY RQ.ServiceDate;
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what the problem is. I'm running this on Access, so I had to put parentheses around the entire phrase after "on" in order for the join to work. However, I still am not getting any zero values.